# Can you use results from 2 sql queries and perform calculations

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I have a requirement to calculate a number value by using the results of two sql queries. I know this is possible in python etc but if I want to use the results of sql queries in say, apache superset, how can I achieve this?

For ex: 
query1: `select * from consumer;` 
result: 190 rows

query2: `select * from producer;` 
result: 230 rows

value I need, called output : `190/230`.
Is this possible using sub queries? How can I extract the output alone?

Comment: show/explain your desired result in a little more detail.

Comment: Just doing this in sql would look something like: `SELECT (SELECT count(*)  FROM consumer)/(SELECT count(*) FROM producer)` I'm not sure that answers your question though.

Comment: Does @jNevill reply answers your question?

Comment: Let me try it out real quick and report back.

Comment: that didn't work - got a vague error - `Please check your query for syntax errors at or near "select". Then, try running your query again.`

Comment: If it's really one row from each query, I'd do something like `select con.theCount/pro.theCount
from
(select count(*) as theCount from consumer) con cross join (select count(*) as theCount from producer) pro`

Comment: I'll try it out. It's not exactly one row - it's only the count of each query. the query is a little longer than what I have mentioned here. The query is `select distinct on (uuid) * from producer where status='abc'`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I finally figured it out thanks to your comment. Much appreciated.